# How does gcc use ah, bh, ch, dh?

Tags: gcc, assembly, compilation, x86

I'm writing on a project where I need to read and process assembly instructions output by gcc. I have several questions regarding some rules of compilation:

1) What are the cases gcc uses ah, bh, ch, dh?

2) Will it still use them if I turn off optimizations?

3) Are there some 'rules' by which gcc transforms source code to assembly if I turn off optimizations? I mean, can I know all the possible scenarios how ah can be used by gcc?

Comment: The compiler may use them any time it thinks it needs 8 bits of storage. Sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to do something related to taint analysis.

Comment: related: [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](//stackoverflow.com/q/41573502) (but the premise of that question is wrong; it *does* use partial registers sometimes, e.g. `foo = (bar >> 8) & 0xFF;` can compile into `movzx ebx, ah` if the compiler did need the full `bar` in EAX for something else.

Comment: Generally gcc avoids the high8 registers; I don't think I've seen it use them as extra 8-bit scratch registers (along with al..dl).  So mostly it uses them for reading the 2nd byte of larger integers, but possibly it could use them for something else.  At `-O0`, it might still use AH within one expression.  There aren't simple rules in general even at `-O0`.    [Disable all optimization options in GCC](//stackoverflow.com/a/33284629)

Comment: GCC will also use AH in combination with the SAHF instruction and the FPU comparison instructions.

Comment: @RossRidge: Only if you compile with `-march=pentium` or something older than P6, though.  Otherwise it will use `fcomi` to compare into EFLAGS directly, avoiding the `fnstsw ax` / `sahf`.  (Or use SSE/SSE2 instead of x87 at all, depending on compile options / target.)